alert() inside useEffect gets triggered before the browser painting is completed. Shouldn't it trigger after the browser is painted?
Let's consider this to be the component:
const Alert = () => {
        useEffect(() => {
            alert("hello");
        }, []);
        return <div>Alert</div>;
    };

My understanding is that useEffect runs after the browser has painted.
But in this code, why does the alert pop up before the browser is painted completely?
NOTE: If it does not happen the first time, try refreshing it.


It is being understood that useEffect runs after the browser has been painted.

This assumption isn't quite right. The documentation states:

When your component is added to the DOM, React will run your setup function.

This doesn't mean the whole application has rendered. It can even run before the DOMContentLoaded event.
As alert() is a blocking function, it will halt the execution of the rest of your code until the message is closed.

I though this was the difference between useEffect and useLayoutEffect. Even in the doc it says "useLayoutEffect is a version of useEffect that fires before the browser repaints the screen." But if you look at the setup section of the doc, both have the same description regarding when the setup gets called. very confusing.
